# Django select on result from QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert the following raw SQL query to Django but I cannot get my head around it. It is quite simple:

```
select * from (select field1, field2, field3, myfunc(field1, field2) as result 
from my_table) as a where a.result>0
```

where `myfunc(field1, field2)` is a user defined function. I have managed to get as far as:

```
my_table.objects.all().annotate(result=RawSQL("myfunc(field1, field2)", ()))
.filter(result__gt=0)
```

but that translates to:

```
select field1, field2, field3, myfunc(field1, field2) as result 
from my_table where myfunc(field1, field2)>0
```

which gives the right answer but it evaluates 'myfunc' twice -- which I do not want as it is bit of time consuming function right now.

Is there any way of doing selects on querysets?

Comment: Do you need the result as well or are you just interested in if its greater than?

Comment: I need the full result.

Comment: I can't think of a way to make the query only do this once I'm afraid (nor can I find a duplicate) but kudos on a good first question. (Btw, the `.all()` isn't needed here)